# Putting a database file into a non web-accessible location

Tags: mysql, linux, debian, phpbb, phpbb3

I installed SQlite (I though that I had installed mysql, but thats another story)

When i try to use it with phpbb, it gives the error

The database file specified is within your board directory tree. You should put this file in a non web-accessible location.

What locations are/are not web-accessible.

and what file should i be moving?

Where should i be moving it to?

Comment: Is /usr/share/ a web-accessible location?

Answer (score 1):

which locations are web-accessible depends on your webserver.

e.g. the default `apache2`-configuration has `/var/www` as the SiteRoot, so all files therein are within web-accessible.

your webserver can have parts of `/usr/share` accessible (e.g. with a `<Directory>` directive).

so: check your webserver's configuration to see which directories are accesible.